# MYSQL Can I find the highest value product in a specific category

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an assignment where I am working with a product database and I need to find the highest priced phone at each store location where the carrier is Sprint. I want to find the phone name and ID.

I.E I want to find the phone.name and phone.id of each Sprint phone store.carrier = "Sprint" where item.price is the greatest of its store.

I have tried a variety of SQL commands sorting by Max(price) and then trying to take distinct values by brand.

Relations:

- store(id, name, carrier)
- phone(id, name, location, price)

Where

- store.id is the primary key of store.
- product.id is the primary key of product.
- product.location is the foreign key that references store.id.

I have tried

```
    SELECT distinct phone.name, phone.id 
      FROM phone
      JOIN store ON phone.location = store.id
     WHERE store.carrier = 'sprint' 
     ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1;
```

and have also tried

```
    SELECT distinct phone.name, phone.id 
      FROM phone
      JOIN store ON phone.location = store.id
     WHERE store.carrier = 'sprint'
       AND phone.price >= (SELECT MAX 
                             FROM (SELECT MAX(price) 
                                     FROM phone 
                                    INNER JOIN store ON phone.location = store.id 
                            GROUP BY location)) 
     GROUP BY phone.id;
```

I expect an output like:

```
+-----+--------------------------+
| ID  |           NAME           |
+-----+--------------------------+
| 12  | iPhone XS MAX            |
| 97  | Samsung Galaxy S10 Plus  |
| 143 | iPhone XS MAX            |
| 163 | Google Pixel 3XL         |
| 194 | iPhone XS MAX            |
+-----+--------------------------+
```

Instead, I get either a list of all the Sprint phones, or just the most valuable phone overall.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

To get top 1 rows, you can use an recursive iteration within the subquery. And then use all row ranking values equals 1 to filter out in the main query :

```
 SELECT q.id phone_id, q.name phone_name, q.store_id
   FROM
   (
    SELECT p.id, p.name, p.location as store_id, p.price,
           @rn := IF(@store = p.location, @rn + 1, 1) AS phone_rank,
           @store := p.location as sto
      FROM phone p
      JOIN (SELECT @store := 1, @rn := 0) as q_iter
     WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM store s WHERE s.id = p.location and s.carrier ='sprint' ) 
     ORDER BY p.location, p.price DESC
    ) q
  WHERE phone_rank = 1  
  ORDER BY q.store_id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b6c794d65c2143f6b5422513bc800aef)</kbd>

Comment: Hi @NoahSolomon. I just copied from your first query. Seems we need to replace with `p.price desc`. Since you're looking for the most expensive products.

Comment: Hi Barbaros. I tried your updated code, but it only gives me the most valuable Sprint phone overall, rather than the most valuable phone per store.